# jquery get element value from string

Tags: jquery

I am using a ajax function to call a php file which retrieve a webpages source code for scraping. when the call back is received it loads all that html into a div container (div_showresults), i am then able to search for key elements and get the values i require. However instead of loading the data into a div container i want to set a variable to that content instead, and then search the variable in the same manner instead of $("#div_showresults") but unsure how to.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'htmlpage-jsonarray.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        data: params,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.success) {

                $("#div_showresults").html(data.result);

                abc = $('#div_showresults span[class=availGreen]').text();
                alert(abc);


                console.log(data.result);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried something simple like `var foo = $(data.result);` …?

Comment: If I understand it right, you want to first check for `availGreen` and then store data.result into `#div_showresults` ?

Comment: @Dhiraji, hi no i just want to store the html code into a variable straight away and then be able to search that variable for several different elements  for values availGree just one of them. I have no need to load the html into a DIV container, its the only way i know how to search.

Comment: @CBroe, one var foo is equal to the html, its the next stage i am stuck with, and thats searching using something simple like span[class=availGreen etc.

Comment: example  var foo = "<div id='one' class='test1'>1</div><div id='two'>2</div>"; i want to be able to search that html code for the container div[id=one] and then access any element in that div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a div on the fly, temporarily store the result in that so that you can search for elements inside it. Like this

`$data = $('<div/>').html(data.result);`

Using `$data.find('')` you can search for elements inside it.

Here is how the method should probably look like

```
success: function(data) {
  if (data.success) {
    $data = $('<div/>').html(data.result);
    // $data.find('span.availGreen')
  }
}
```

Here is a demo **http://jsbin.com/nudune/1/edit?html,js,output**
In the demo, the ajax fetches content from another HTML file and searches for a particular span.

Comment: thank you, one more thing when searching in the example i gave, how would i use the following in your example.  $("#div_showresults tbody td[id=cell][data-sku=123][data-field=price]").text()

Comment: `$data.find("tbody td[id=cell][data-sku=123][data-field=price]").text()` this should do. Anything you want to search for from the fetched HTML should be done using `$data.find(....)`